# SQL function in view table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this function which shows years, months and days between dates. On a view table I have data with start and finish dates. How is it possible to integrate that function it into my view table?

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter FUNCTION [db].[GetDateDifference]
(
    @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS
 @DateDifference TABLE (
 YEAR INT,  MONTH INT, DAYS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME
    SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate),
              @FromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
    SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
              @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
    SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
              @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    INSERT INTO @DateDifference
    VALUES(@Years, @Months, @Days)

    RETURN
END
```

and here is my view table:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter VIEW [db].[View_ServiceTickets]

AS

SELECT  TOP 99 

        ServiceTicketDate,
        BillingDate as 'Project Finished',
        InspectionScheduleDate


FROM        tblServiceTicket INNER JOIN
            tblServiceTicketReport on tblServiceTicket.ServiceTicketID = tblServiceTicketReport.ServiceTicketID 


where  ServiceTicketDate > '2016'
order by ServiceTicketDate desc

GO
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag your code appears to be using this database.

Comment: You know, this could be accomplished even on client-side. What's the purpose of computed values?

Comment: @Ivan Starostin I need this for excel report.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the return data type of your function is a table, so you use treat it as a table.
you can test the following:

```
alter VIEW [db].[View_ServiceTickets]

AS

SELECT  TOP 99 

    ServiceTicketDate,
    BillingDate as 'Project Finished',
    InspectionScheduleDate,
    d.*


FROM        tblServiceTicket INNER JOIN
        tblServiceTicketReport on tblServiceTicket.ServiceTicketID = tblServiceTicketReport.ServiceTicketID 
        OUTER APPLY(SELECT YEAR,MONTH,DAYS FROM [db].[GetDateDifference](ServiceTicketDate,BillingDate)) d


where  ServiceTicketDate > '2016'
order by ServiceTicketDate desc
```

Comment: im getting -7 years, 6 months, 23 days with these dates: 2010-06-21 and 2016-11-28. I changed the possition of ServiceTicketDate and BillingDate and its now fine, 6y,5m,7d. But how to return it to one column? I have this example http://sqlhints.com/2015/07/10/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql-server/ but if I use scalar function your code does not work.

Comment: @Fresher what exactly do you need to show in Excel? What is the correct result for `2010-06-21 and 2016-11-28`? Specifically for Excel report.

Comment: @Ivan Starostin the correct result is 6y,5m,7d which is fine from Nolan Shang script. But  its in 3 different columns http://sqlhints.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Difference-between-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql.jpg. I need to have it in one column as here: http://sqlhints.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Difference-between-dates-in-years-months-and-days-by-scalar-function-in-sql.jpg (Difference between the dates)

Comment: @Fresher, so the correct answer is a string? `"6y, 5m, 7d"`? This is how it must be displayed in Excel? And used there as a string which has nothing common with date or number, right?